# Understanding the minmax pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode, minimax

I'm teaching myself the minimax algorithm and I just had a few questions I was hoping someone could answer.

Firstly on line 05 - what does `:=` mean?

Also on line 08/14 I notice that the method `max` or `min` is called with two arguments, what would this method return? Would it return the maximum value or the minimum value found so far? Is there a pseudocode example of this or am I misunderstanding?

```
01 function minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer)
02     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return the heuristic value of node

04     if maximizingPlayer
05         bestValue := −∞
06         for each child of node
07             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, FALSE)
08             bestValue := max(bestValue, v)
09         return bestValue

10     else    (* minimizing player *)
11         bestValue := +∞
12         for each child of node
13             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, TRUE)
14             bestValue := min(bestValue, v)
15         return bestValue
```

Comment: := is an assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a pseudocode example of this or am I misunderstanding?". It's already in pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `bestValue := −∞`: Assign negative infinity (the lowest possible number) to `bestValue`
- `max(bestValue, v)` returns `bestValue` *or* `v`, whichever is *bigger*
- `min(bestValue, v)` returns `bestValue` *or* `v`, whichever is *smaller*

Since this is pseudocode, we can assume that any language you will use to implement it provides the functions `max` and `min`. If not, you can easily implement them yourself.